# Android - customize "your recent screens appear here" / "your recent apps" screen

Tags: android, android-launcher, device-admin

I realy dint know how this screen is named :/ i called it after the message it shows when no app is running "your recent screens appear here". It basicly shows all apps currently runnning on the device.

So you know what im talking about here screens (sry big and spammy) with and without running apps. The second screen also shows the google widget i want to get rid off.
[image]
[image]

Is there a way to adjust the "your recent screens appear here" screen on Android phones and Tablets? 
Is there a solution without using the Device Administration API? 
If the Device Administration API is required - where can i find a documentation/tutorial that teaches me how to do it?

Currently we created a Launcher App for Android in order to deny access to most other Apps. It only shows our app and the android settings.

Unfortunately there is an Google Widget on the "your recent screens appear here" screen. It is the same widget shown on the Home screen, when using the default launcher. When i disable the Google Application the Widget disappears properly from the Home screen, but leaves a "Couldn´t add widget" message on the "your recent screens appear here" screen.
Currently we are looking for an easy solution to get rid of that widget.

Comment: Am I the only one who didn't get what is the "your recent screens appear here" screen? If not, could you add screenshots?

Comment: I assume they mean the one that appears on long-pressing the home button.

Comment: added screens - sry for the confusion

Comment: @Aligertor i think what you mean is the "overview screen" :) you can find some guides on how to add tasks there here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/recents.html

Comment: @Aligertor also you can use Activity.setTaskDescrption to change some properties like the label, bitmap/icon and the primary color https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setTaskDescription(android.app.ActivityManager.TaskDescription)

Comment: just read the rest of the question... i think to get rid of the google widget you'll have to go deeper into the system and modify the SystemUI app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is actually no way to customize this page without changes in the OS.

still i found a workarround to get rid of the widget.
when starting an App i add a flag that prevents it from beeing displayed in the recent apps screen. this way the user only sees the empty recent apps screen which has no widget.

```
Intent i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(apps.get(pos).name.toString());
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
HomeActivity.this.startActivity(i);
```